# micro cloudfoundry - vmc target FAILED Target refused connection

Tags: cloud-foundry

I cannot get micro cloudfoundry to work, I can ping it no problem, but when I try and run 
vmc target....

vmc target api.xxx.cloudfoundry.me
Setting target to http://api.xxx.cloudfoundry.me... FAILED
Target refused connection.

found this error in te logs...

/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:92:in `getaddress'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/network.rb:61:in`block in lookup'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/network.rb:73:in `resolv_guard'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/network.rb:60:in`lookup'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/watcher.rb:83:in `check'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/watcher.rb:46:in`watch'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/watcher.rb:26:in `block in start'

## [725] ERROR: watcher caught: Connection refused - recvfrom(2)

/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:747:in `recv'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:747:in`recv_reply'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:641:in `request'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:506:in`block in each_resource'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:1000:in `block (3 levels) in resolv'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:998:in`each'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:998:in `block (2 levels) in resolv'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:997:in`each'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:997:in `block in resolv'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:995:in`each'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:995:in `resolv'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:498:in`each_resource'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:391:in `each_address'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:115:in`block in each_address'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:114:in `each'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:114:in`each_address'
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb:92:in `getaddress'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/network.rb:61:in`block in lookup'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/network.rb:73:in `resolv_guard'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/network.rb:60:in`lookup'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/watcher.rb:83:in `check'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/watcher.rb:46:in`watch'
/var/vcap/micro/lib/micro/watcher.rb:26:in `block in start'

does anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

this is what I have installed...

vmc version 0.5.0
vmware fusion Professional Version 5.0.3 (1040386)
micro cloud version: micro-v119-20121113.000224
mac osx 10.0.3